# There are just two people left who can speak it fluently

Tags: punctuation

> There are just two people left **who can speak it fluently** – but they refuse to talk to each other.

Source: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2011/apr/13/mexico-language-ayapaneco-dying-out

---

I think that "**who can speak it fluently**" is a non-restrictive relative clause and that a comma should be before "**who**".
What do you say?

Comment: No: It's a restrictive relative and no comma is required.

Comment: Some people have apparently been taught that a restrictive relative clause must begin "that", but [that isn't true](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/using-that-and-which-is-all-about-restrictive-and-non-restrictive-clauses/) and "who" is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extract part of the passage:

> There are just two people left who can speak it fluently – but they refuse to talk to each other.  Manuel Segovia, 75, and Isidro Velazquez, 69, live 500 metres apart in the *village* of Ayapa ... *people* who know them say they have never really enjoyed each other's company.

*who can speak it fluently* has to be a restrictive relative clause.

It is unlikely that a village can have only two people.  It is also unlikely that *people who know them*, shown above, and *son and wife* in paragraph 5 are not living there.

Edit

If "who can speak it fluently" is a non-restrictive relative clause, it would mean the village has just two people.  As I have explained, that is unlikely.

There seems to be a clarification about this story.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayapa_Zoque)

> In 2010 a story started circulating that the last two speakers of the Ayapaneco language were enemies and no longer talked to each other.  The story was incorrect ...